# How can I set the S3 object lifecycle using boto?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I have uploaded several files to Amazon S3 using [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto). However, I failed to set a lifecycle using statement (I know this can be done using the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/), but I need to allow each user to decide how long want to keep the file).

The [boto API reference for S3](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html?highlight=lifecycle) properly documents [configure_lifecycle(lifecycle_config, headers=None)](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html?highlight=lifecycle#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.configure_lifecycle) as the solution, but I'm unable to configure this. Can anyone correct my code?

Thanks!

```
key='key'
secretkey='secretkey'

#build the connection
conn = S3Connection(key, secretkey)
bucket = conn.create_bucket('przm')
k=Key(bucket)

#select and upload the file
name1='run1'
k.key=name1
k.set_contents_from_filename('RUN')
link1='https://s3.amazonaws.com/przm/'+name1
#allow anyone can download this file
k.set_acl('public-read-write')

#delete this file after one day. Can anyone give me some help here?
configure_lifecycle(lifecycle_config, headers=None)
```

Answer (score 5):

You aren't showing where "lifecycle_config" comes from in this example.  However, what you should do is create a Lifecycle object, like this:

```
import boto.s3.lifecycle
lifecycle_config = boto.s3.lifecycle.Lifecycle()
lifecycle_config.add_rule('lc_rule_1', '/', 'Enabled', 1)
```

See class [boto.s3.lifecycle](http://readthedocs.org/docs/boto/en/latest/ref/s3.html#module-boto.s3.lifecycle) for details about the Lifecycle object and what the above parameters mean.

Once you have a Lifecycle object, you can then use that in the call to [configure_lifecycle()](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html?highlight=lifecycle#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.configure_lifecycle), like this:

```
bucket.configure_lifecycle(lifecycle_config)
```